# main() function defined without return type gives warning

Tags: c, types, return, program-entry-point

This is my program:

```
main()
{ 
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

I get this warning when compiling it:

```
function should return a value
```

When changing `main()` to `void main()`, the warning disappears.

Why is that so?

Comment: This is something you could have found with a simple search [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356510/int-main-vs-void-main-in-c)

Comment: It should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 11):

There are few things which you should take note of :

1. The `int` is the `main()` function's return type. That means that the kind of value `main()` can
   return is an integer.
2. `main( )` was tolerated by the C90 compilers but not by C99 compilers which means its not a part of C99 standard anymore , so don't do this.
3. `void main()` is not a standard form ,some compilers allow this, but none of the standards have ever listed it as an option. Therefore,
   compilers don't have to accept this form, and several don't. **Again, stick to the standard form,
   and you won't run into problems if you move a program from one compiler to another.**
4. And one last thing , instead of writing main like this :

   `int main()` // **here you are being silent about passing arguments to main , meaning it may or may not take arguments**

write like this :

```
int main(void)// this specifies there are no arguments taken by main
```

**You might wanna look at the** [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) **for further details**.

Comment: Point 4 is wrong. As a definition, `int main() { ... }` is identical to `int main(void) { ... }`. It's only as a declaration (i.e. `int main();`) that the form without `void` leaves the arguments unspecified.

Comment: @R..: A function definition includes a declaration. `int main()` will probably be accepted by any existing compiler, but you should still use `int main(void)`. I've discussed this further [here](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-standard-quibbles.html).

Answer (score 7):

Quick summary: If you don't want to use command-line arguments, you should write:

```
int main(void) {
    /* body of main function */
}
```

If you do:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

These are the *only* portable ways to define the `main` function.

You should *probably* have a `return 0;` at the end, though it's not strictly necessary. Returning `0` indicates successful execution. There are ways to indicate that execution failed; I won't get into that here.

There's some history behind this. The rules for a valid definition of the `main` function have changed a bit across different releases of the C standard.

Before the introduction of the first official standard for C in 1989, the most common form was:

```
main()
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Or, if you wanted to use command-line arguments:

```
main(argc, argv)
/* argc is implicitly of type int */
char *argv[];
{
    /* ... */
}
```

There was no way to define a function that didn't return a value. If you didn't specify a return type, it defaulted to `int`.

The 1989 ANSI C standard (which was republished with editorial changes as the 1990 ISO C standard) introduced *prototypes*, function declarations and definitions that specify the parameter types.  There are two equally valid definitions for `main`. You can use one or the other depending on whether you need to use command line arguments:

```
int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

(`char *argv[]` can also be written as `char **argv`. This rule applies only to parameter definitions.)

A given compiler may or may not choose to permit other forms. For example, some compilers support a third parameter `envp`.

Somehow, some authors have gotten the idea that `void main()` or `void main(void)` is valid. It can be valid *for some particular compiler*, but only if that compiler explicitly supports it. It's not portable. The odd thing about this is that the same standard that first introduced the `void` keyword simultaneously established the rule that `main`'s return type is `int`.

`void main()` is useful as an indicator that the author of the book you're reading doesn't know the C language very well, and that you should find another book.

The story is different for "freestanding" (embedded) systems. For such systems, the program's entry point is entirely implementation-defined, and might not even be called `main`. Defining it as `void main(void)` may well be valid *for such systems*.

The 1999 ISO C standard dropped the "implicit int" rule.  Taking advantage of that rule was probably never a good idea in the first place. As of ISO C 1990, you could legally use:

```
main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

because it was equivalent to:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

As of the 1999 standard, the `int` is mandatory.

The 1999 standard also added a special-case rule: reaching the closing `}` of the `main` function is equivalent to executing `return 0;`. It's still not a bad idea to add the explicit `return 0;`, especially if your code might be compiled with a pre-C99 compiler.

The 2011 ISO C standard didn't make any changes in this area.

The difference between `int main()` and `int main(void)` is that the latter explicitly says that `main` takes no arguments; the former doesn't specify how many arguments it takes. Use the `int main(void)` form. There have been debates about whether `int main()` is even legal.

You can likely get away with writing `void main()`, since it's an error that compilers are not actually required to diagnose (it's *undefined behavior* unless the implementation documents it).

The bottom line: The proper definition of `main` has a long and varied history, and there are a lot of variant forms you can probably get away with using. But unless you're programming for an embedded system, there is no point in using anything other than one of the two officially valid forms:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Quite an extensive answer from someone who survived all these evolutions... Is this simpler alternative OK: `int main() { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @chqrlie: Depends on how you define "OK". `int main()` is not a prototype, and non-prototype function declarations and definitions are "obsolescent" according to the C standard. I think that any C compiler will accept `int main() { /* ... */ }`, and I believe it was the intent of the authors of the standard that it should be acceptable, but the standard doesn't actually say it is.  I've discussed this at some length here: [Is int main() necessarily valid? Should it be?](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2014/02/c-standard-quibbles.html#more).

Answer (score 1):

c automatically implies the datatype `int` to functions with no declared datatype. So as far as the compiler is concerned the above is:

```
int main()
{ 
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

This expects that you would return an integer at the end of it with a `return` statement. If you explicitly specify it as `void main()` you are telling the compiler that the function does not have a return value, hence no warning.

The reason that this is not an error is that if not specified, `main()` will `return 0;` at the end of execution. However the compiler is still giving you a warning that this is happening.

Best practice is to use `int main()` and then `return 0` at the end of your program execution like this.

```
int main()
{ 
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493440/why-no-compiler-error-for-main-without-a-return-at-the-end?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: No, `void main` is invalid, always use `int main`.

Comment: The 1999 ISO C standard dropped the "implicit int" rule, making `main(){}` invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You got the warning because you didn't specify the return type of `main`.

You should always use `int main`, and return an `int` number, usually `0` for success.

```
int main()
{ 
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;      //you can omit this since C99
}
```

Using `void main` on a hosted environment(normally we are, if not, the following doesn't have to be true) leads to undefined behavior, even though it works in some compilers, **never** use it.

The standard says `main` has two kinds of prototype, both returns `int`:

C11 5.1.2.2.1 *Program startup*

> The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Actually, the first edition of K&R C did not specify the type of main() in the hello world example.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 that is because K&R C 1st ed. *pre-dates* ANSI/ISO C (C89/90). In K&R and C89/90, there was the "implicit int" rule which stated that functions omitting return type were automatically considered returning `int`. C99 dropped this rule, so not specifying a return type for `main()` in K&R and C89/90 was fine, but nowadays, it's not, and honestly unless you are in an environment that pre-dates ANSI/ISO C, you honestly should never make use of the implicit int rule. (Look at Keith Thompson's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18165362/1701799).)

Comment: yeah, @RastaJedi - I know it predates ANSI. I thought basically everyone knew that.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 there are actually a surprising number of people who confuse the 'K&R' moniker because of the 2nd ed. of the book. It's interesting that they didn't use a return type for that example, +1.

Comment: @RastaJedi The name 'C89' (read: 1989) and the original first edition publishing date would have tipped me off.

Answer (score 1):

write

```
return 0 ;
```

at the last line.

Comment: Please add more description to your answer