# Why setting breakpoints and running it fail (Chapter 2 shellcoder's handbook)

Tags: gdb, virtual-machine, buffer-overflow, kali-linux

I reading the shellcoder's handbook and trying to attempt problems the book provides. However, given that the book was written over a decade ago, it is very hard to follow along. One of the problems I had trouble with was setting up breakpoints at calls to gets and printf after I disasembled the function that is using it. Whenever I would set a breakpoint and run it my program would stop. I would just love to understand why. This is chapter 2 assignment dealing with the particular section dealing Overflowing Buffers on the stack. I am running my code on a 64 bit Kali Lix vim. Here is the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void return_input (void){
    char array[30];

    gets(array);
    printf("%s\n", array);
}

main(){
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code with these flags cc -m32 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -ggdb -fmax-errors=1 -w overflow.c -o overflow and it gave me this when I disasembled it, put breaks on gets and prinft and tried to run it.[image]

Like I said I am more interested in why I not able to get the program to run up till the breakpoint.

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but it's a good idea to do anyway: when creating your `main` function, always use `int main()`. Look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158541/main-function-defined-without-return-type-gives-warning) for more info on why.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show the text of your GDB session instead.

Comment: Are you asking about the reason of `Stopped` in output (why gdb is stopping itself)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting breakpoints on the wrong addresses, because you have disassembled the binary before it has been relocated, and you have a position-independent executable.

Position independent executables do no run at the linked-at address (usually 0), but instead are relocated to a random address.

Re-build your binary again, adding `-fno-pie -no-pie` flags. This will build a position-dependent executable, with addresses like `0x08049152`. This binary will actually run at exactly the address that it was linked at, and your breakpoints will work.

Comment: Hey can explain "disassembled the binary before it has been relocated, and you have a position-independent executable" I don't understand it. Also what does -fno-pie -no-pie do?

Comment: 1) First off not helpless curious. 2) ultimately I was going to do that anyway and, using a search engine isn't an end all be all for all of life's questions. Lastly, 3), some stuff like the compiler flags are either too specific for a search engine to be of use or reading the documentation, in this case, man pages for gcc, becomes pretty esoteric that you end getting lost

Comment: "ultimately I was going to do that anyway " -- well, what are you waiting for? Answer updated.