# Conceptual help in printing "hello world" without using a semi-colon

Tags: c

I have learned that the `if` condition can take one of 2 values, 0 or 1, as input.

Now I've stumbled upon the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    if (printf("Hello World")) { } 
}
```

In the condition we have a function does not give 0 or 1 whereas gives a set of characters as an output.

At first I expected an error, but I didn't get one and the code runs OK.

Can someone please explain me the reason for this behavior

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the `printf` [specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? In particular, it's return value?

Comment: printf will return the number of characters printed. On your case the result will be implicity converted to bool (different from 0 means true and false if 0)

Comment: A function in C does not "give" anyhing. A function might *return a value* and also might *have side effects*. You should learn what `printf` returns and what side effects it has

Comment: Also, `if` can take any number, not just 0 or 1: it treats zero as false and any other value as true.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu: There's no implicit conversion to "bool" in C.

Comment: *"... I have learnt that "if" condition can only take 0 or 1 as input. "* - that's wrong; It takes any expression convertible to an integer value, where zero equates to false, and non-zero equates to true.

Comment: The `if` condition can be an expression with any scalar type, so it is not restricted to the values 0 or 1. It could even be a floating point value or a pointer. If the expression compares unequal to 0, the `if` part is executed. Otherwise, the optional `else` part is executed if it exists.

Comment: @WhozCraig It doesn't need to be convertible to an integer value.

Comment: Another way to look at it is if the condition evaluates to `0` the `if (condition)` tests false, any non-zero condition causes `if (condition)` to test true.

Comment: Or another way is to consider that `if (condition)` is equivalent to `if ((condition) != 0)`.

Comment: The body of an IF statement it can be empty, because the condition self of an IF is a statement, hence there is no need of the semicolon when using a function as an IF condition. So it’s depends of which level are you saying that you use a function without semicolon....

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493440/why-no-compiler-error-for-main-without-a-return-at-the-end

Comment: @KevinKouketsu, it will not be _converted_ to bool, it will be _interpreted_ as bool, as per the C specification.

Comment: Please note that there is a huge difference between the "output" a function produces (in simplified terms, "what it writes to the terminal, if anything at all") and its "return value" (the value it hands back to whatever called the funtion). printf _outputs_ text but _returns_ a number, namely the number of characters written.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie and Bathsheba yes, both are right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have learnt that "if" condition can only take 0 or 1 as input.

Absolutely not true.  A condition can take almost anything, which is interpreted as false if it's equal to 0, or true if it's not equal to 0.

> I was expecting an error when I first saw it but because of printf but it isn't giving.

Right.  Why would you expect an error?  `printf` returns an `int` value, so it's perfectly fine.  (And in this case, it doesn't even matter whether `printf` returns zero or nonzero, because there's nothing that happens in the body of the `if` statement.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @jaideep One more thing: If (based on the title of your original post) this all stemmed from a "cute puzzle" along the lines of "Can you figure out how to write a program that prints 'Hello, word' without using any semicolons?", I wouldn't worry about that kind of puzzle very much, because it's not clear they teach you anything useful about programming.